# Lua latin characters in tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm new in Lua and looking for internet I don't find a solution to my problem, or an answer if I actually can do the next thing.

I have the next table. As you can see the key has a **í**:

```
DB = {
    ["Vigía"] = 112
}
```

If I try to retrieve that value from the table it returns **nil**.
I tried removing the **í** character and then I can get the value 112.

Can I use latin characters as a key in this scenario?,

Thanks!

Comment: How are you retrieving the value? Using `"Vigia"` (without the accent) won't work, but if you have the accent then it should work.

Comment: I use `DB["Vigía"]` with the accent, and I get null. However If I rename it to `Vigia` and then I try `DB["Vigia"]` it works. But I need the accent in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to, but there are [some caveats (lua-users.org)](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode)

[I've run your code at ideone](http://ideone.com/zn8WoG), and it works fine. Perhaps your editor is doing something weird? What version of Lua are you using?

```
DB = {
    ["Vigía"] = 112
}

print(DB["Vigía"])

print(_VERSION)
```

Result:

```
Success time: 0.02 memory: 2540 signal:0
112
Lua 5.1
```

Comment: I'm developing an addon for World of Warcraft, so I'm assuming if it works to you that it might be an issue with the game :/. Thank's for your time @Advert.

Comment: @maqjav It looks like World of Warcraft should support UTF-8: http://www.wowwiki.com/Localizing_an_addon

Comment: I just found my problem. Silly of me, the file that contains the table was in UTF-8 encoding, but the file where I was retreaving the value was in ANSI :). Now both are in UTF-8 and it works like a charm! Thanks anyway!